# Remove item from PopupMenuButton while it is open

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-state

I have a `PopupMenuButton` that displays some `PopupMenuItem<String>`'s generated from a `List<String>`. Each item has a delete button, which removes the `String` from the list. The problem is that the popup menu doesn't get rebuilt after deleting an item, until it's closed and opened again.

It seems that no matter what I do, even using a `GlobalKey` and calling `key.currentState.setState()`, it doesn't cause the popup menu to be rebuilt until it's closed and opened again.

```
  GlobalKey _favoritesKey = new GlobalKey();

  PopupMenuButton<String>(
      key: _favoritesKey,
      icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border),
      itemBuilder: (context){
          List<PopupMenuItem<String>> result = [];
          model.favorites.forEach((x){
              result.add(PopupMenuItem<String>(value: x, child: Row(
                  children: [
                      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline), onPressed: (){
                          model.removeFavorite(x);
                          _favoritesKey.currentState?.setState((){});
                          setState(() {});
                      }),
                      Text(x)
                  ]
              )));
          });
          return result;
      },
      onSelected: (x){
          // Do something with the selected value
      },
  )
```

How can I make the popup menu rebuild itself while it is opened?

Comment: did u find a solution? i am at the same situation. I have a list in a PopupMenubtn and i want to delete an item in the popupmenu and it should update while its open.